# Env variables not being picked up by script

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

￼Creating a script to pass to a few different people and ran into an `env` problem. The script wouldn't run unless I supplied it with `$PATH`, `$HOME`, and `$GOPATH` at the beginning of the file. Like so:

```sh
HOME=/home/Hustlin

PATH=/home/Hustlin/bin:/home/Hustlin/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/bin:/home/Hustlin/go/bin

export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

This is not advantageous when trying to pass the script around and each person has to set these variables themselves. This file would rarely be run by the User and would most often be run via `crontab`.

I would love to hear a better way of coding this so I'm not asking everyone I send the script to update these variables.

Thank you all in advance!!!

EDIT 
The script is being run via `crontab` with no special permissions.

```sh
1,16,31,46 * * * * /home/Hustlin/directory1/super_cool_script.sh
```

Here is the script I am running:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# TODO Manually put your $PATH and $HOME here. 

PATH=/home/Hustlin/bin:/home/Hustlin/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/bin:/home/Hustlin/go/bin

HOME=/home/Hustlin

export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin

# Field1
field1="foo"

# Welcome message. 
echo Starting the update process...

# Deposit directory.
mkdir -p $HOME/directory1/sub1/data/body
mkdir -p $HOME/directory1/sub2/system

# Run command
program1 command1 

# Run longer command. 
program1 command2 field1

sleep 3

program1 command3 -o $HOME/directory1/sub1/data $field1

sleep 1

# Unzip and discard unnecessary files.
unzip $HOME/directory1/sub1/data/$field1 -d $HOME/directory1/sub1/data

rm $HOME/directory1/sub1/data/bar.yaml $HOME/dircetory1/sub1/data/char.txt

rm $HOME/directory1/sub1/data/$field1.zip

# Rename
mv $HOME/directory1/sub1/data/body.json $HOME/directory1/sub1/data/body/$(date -d '1 hour ago' +%d-%m-%Y_%H).json

echo Process complete.
```

I changed most of the program and command names for privacy. What I did post still represents what is being done and how the files are being moved.

Comment: How is the script being executed (is it via sudo or something else)? Can you echo those variables first and then execute the script? **EDIT** Please post a minimum script that demonstrates the problem. You are only showing your workaround.

Comment: If your script requires that $HOME contain the path of your home directory instead of the home directory of the user running the script, I would argue that your script is horribly broken.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Sorry, I probably worded it poorly. Currently, each person has to update the script with their own `$HOME` and `env` variables. I would like to make it easier on them by having this take place automatically. I am not advocating that my `$HOME` should be the `$HOME` for everyone :)

Comment: You appear to be using `HOME` when you could be using any arbitrary name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is crontab, not the script.
When you run the script on your terminal, you are logged in a session with all environment variables set, so the script can use it.
But when you run it from crontab it an "empty" session, so it does not have any environment variable set, it doesn't even know about your user.

Run the script on crontab like this:. 
`su --login Hustlin /home/Hustlin/directory1/super_cool_script.sh`

Check this documentation.
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html

Comment: Thank you for replying! I was able to add `35 * * * * su --login Hustlin "/home/Hustlin/test1.sh" ` to `sudo crontab -e`. Is there a way to do this **without** sudo?

Answer (score 1):

`bash -l -c /path/to/script` will make bash execute all .bashrc and .profile files first, so it will have HOME and PATH variables set.